# Fetching data first time from API endpoint it return empty array, after that return array with real information

Tags: reactjs, fetch, fetch-api, use-effect, react-context

I created React Context, and in it fetching data from API endpoint. Problem is when it's fetching data first time it return empty array, after that return array with real informations. I used useEffect() Hook to fetch data every time when searchTerm change.

Hence, I've been unable to access the individual items - movies, because I tried to access the array with no elements (at the first time fetching data).

I think there is another problem, app using context in other components before fetch data in context.js component.

How to fix these problems?

My code in context.js is:

```
const AppContext = React.createContext();

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
 const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
 const [series, setSeries] = useState([]);
 const [searchedMovies, setSearchedMovies] = useState([]);
 const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

 const API_KEY = 'api_key=6f65985ba5185e62a6b869c6001fc2f6';
 const BASE_URL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';
 const MOVIES_URL =
   BASE_URL + '/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&' + API_KEY;

 const SERIES_URL =
   BASE_URL + '/discover/tv?sort_by=popularity.desc&' + API_KEY;

 const SEARCH_MOVIES_URL = BASE_URL + '/search/movie?' + API_KEY + '&query=';
 const SEARCH_SERIES_URL = BASE_URL + '/search/tv?' + API_KEY + '&query=';
 const img_url = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500';

 const data = [
   { name: 'movies', content: movies },
   { name: 'series', content: series },
 ];

 const fetchItems = (url, setItems) => {
   setLoading(true);
   fetch(url)
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((data) => {
       const { results } = data;
       console.log(data);

       if (results) {
         const newMovies = results.map((item) => {
           const { title, name, id, overview, vote_average, poster_path } =
             item;

           return {
             id,
             title,
             name,
             info: overview.slice(0, 150),
             image: img_url + poster_path,
             vote: vote_average,
           };
         });
         console.log(newMovies);
         setItems(newMovies);
       } else {
         setItems([]);
       }
       setLoading(false);
     });
 };

 useEffect(() => {
   if (searchTerm) {
     fetchItems(SEARCH_MOVIES_URL + searchTerm, setMovies);
     fetchItems(SEARCH_SERIES_URL + searchTerm, setSeries);
   }
   fetchItems(MOVIES_URL, setMovies);
   fetchItems(SERIES_URL, setSeries);
 }, [searchTerm]);

 const handleOnSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
 };

 const getMovie = (id) => {
   let tempMovies = [...movies];
   console.log(tempMovies);
   const movie = tempMovies.find((movie) => movie.id === id);
   return movie;
 };

 return (
   <AppContext.Provider
     value={{
       loading,
       movies,
       series,
       searchTerm,
       handleOnSubmit,
       setSearchTerm,
       getMovie,
       setMovies,
       searchedMovies,
       data,
     }}
   >
     {children}
   </AppContext.Provider>
 );
};

export const useGlobalContext = () => {
 return useContext(AppContext);
};

export { AppContext, AppProvider };
```

Comment: You can keep an object with sample data having same keys as your response but no values and check in useEffect if length of retured data is equal to 0 then push that sample data in that array and set is as state.

Answer (score 0):

You have already set the loading state when fetching the data. So, once the data is completely fetched then it will render `AppContext.Provider` else it will not render. Try this:

```
 return loading ? (
    <>Fetching data...</>
  ) : (
    <AppContext.Provider
     value={{
       loading,
       movies,
       series,
       searchTerm,
       handleOnSubmit,
       setSearchTerm,
       getMovie,
       setMovies,
       searchedMovies,
       data,
     }}
   >
     {children}
   </AppContext.Provider>
 )
```

Comment: How to do fetching  the data in the return statement if loading is true, then I can't use useEffect() what is important for app for changing movie items depends on searchTerm? Could you write this part of the code?

Comment: the `fetching data...` is just a text to show when data is being fetched just like loading screen or progress bar. In `fetchItem` you have set `setLoading(true)` and once it has completed you have set `setLoading(false)`, which means now `loading==false`. Then in the return statement, we are just rendering the data once loading is finished or `loading==false`, which means data has been fetched. And once data has been fetched we return `AppContext.Provider`. I hope you know of [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)